# create string var names from string and int - not getting expected result

Tags: string, integer, concatenation

I have tried at least 4 variations I found on stackoverflow to produce a list of variable names and they all produce the same (unintended) result. Here's the MCVE:

```
string='v'
["string" + str(i) for i in range(1,11)]
print(string)

v
```

What I intended was v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

made several mistakes by not carefully understanding the previous answers:

> string='v'
>       list=[string + str(i) for i in range(1,11)]
>   print(list)

['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v9', 'v10']